# Javascript merging an array with array objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var authors = [
             {authorIndex:1,    author:"John Steinbeck"},
             {authorIndex:2,    author:"Franz Kafka"},
             {authorIndex:3,    author:"J. R. R. Tolkien"},
             {authorIndex:4,    author:"Charles Dickens"}];
var books = [
    {title:"The Grapes of Wrath",authorIndex:4,pubYear:1936},
    {title:"The Hobbit",authorIndex:2,pubYear:1937},
    {title:"The Trial",authorIndex:1,pubYear:1937},
    {title:"A Tale of Two Cities",authorIndex:3,pubYear:1859}];
```

What I want to do is insert authors in books and to be connected with authorsIndex

Comment: please add the result and the code, you tried. --> [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Considering your `authors` array will have unique `authorIndex` values, first create an object having `authorIndex` as keys and relevant object as its value. Then iterate over your `books` array and merge object properties using `Object.assign()`:

```js
var authors = [
  {authorIndex:1, author:"John Steinbeck"}, {authorIndex:2, author:"Franz Kafka"},
  {authorIndex:3, author:"J. R. R. Tolkien"}, {authorIndex:4, author:"Charles Dickens"}
];
var books = [
  {title:"The Grapes of Wrath",authorIndex:4,pubYear:1936},
  {title:"The Hobbit",authorIndex:2,pubYear:1937},
  {title:"The Trial",authorIndex:1,pubYear:1937},
  {title:"A Tale of Two Cities",authorIndex:3,pubYear:1859}
];
    
var authorsObj = authors.reduce((r, c) => (r[c.authorIndex] = c, r), {});

var result = books.map(o => Object.assign(o, authorsObj[o.authorIndex]));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    const result = authors.map(val => {
        return Object.assign({}, val, books.filter(v => v.authorIndex === val.authorIndex)[0]);
        console.log(result);
    });
    console.log(result);
```

**This is will give the combined array of both authors and books**

Answer (score 0):

```
books.forEach(function(value,index){
  var ind = value.authorIndex;
  var matchAuthor = authors.find(function(element){
    return element.authorIndex == ind;
  });
  value.author = matchAuthor.author;
})
```

There are a lot of solutions one of them is this, Please check the [link](https://codepen.io/shakogele/pen/mzWPKw)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another concise option using lodash for those who are interested:

```js
var authors = [{ authorIndex: 1, author: "John Steinbeck" }, { authorIndex: 2, author: "Franz Kafka" }, { authorIndex: 3, author: "J. R. R. Tolkien" }, { authorIndex: 4, author: "Charles Dickens" } ];
var books = [{ title: "The Grapes of Wrath", authorIndex: 4, pubYear: 1936 }, { title: "The Hobbit", authorIndex: 2, pubYear: 1937 }, { title: "The Trial", authorIndex: 1, pubYear: 1937 }, { title: "A Tale of Two Cities", authorIndex: 3, pubYear: 1859 } ];

const aMap = _.keyBy(authors, 'authorIndex')
const result = _.map(books, x => _.merge(x, aMap[x.authorIndex]))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

We do [keyBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#keyBy) to make sure we have a key map for reference and them we map and for each item we do [merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#merge).